# distanceto functon Returning wrong format Android

Tags: android, location

I am calculating distance between two location using latitude and longitude... i am getting the distance easily and converting it into miles... but first difference value come in wrong format and other value coming right.

First distance is coming like this = 2.0E-4
While other like this = 48.8881

i have used the following code

```
Location l1 = new Location("One");
        l1.setLatitude(cur_latitude);
        l1.setLongitude(cur_longitude);

        for (int i = 0; i < lctn.size(); i++) {
            Location l2 = new Location("LocationB");
            l2.setLatitude(lctn.get(i).getLocation_lat());
            l2.setLongitude(lctn.get(i).getLocation_lng());
            float distance = l1.distanceTo(l2);
            distance =Float.parseFloat(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format( distance / 1000.0f));
            Double mile = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(distance * 0.6214));

            Log.e("km_", "" + distance);
            Log.e("miles_", "" + mile);
```

Also please check whether i am using right formula for calculating miles....Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Distance is in points that why it happening, You need to use accuracy variable and assign some value to this variable,
in my case i use

```
int accuracy = 20;
```

Then compare this accuracy with Location accuracy

```
if(l2.getAccuracy() <= accuracy ) {
Log.e("km_", "" + distance);
Log.e("miles_", "" + mile);
}
```

I suggest you to use fused location api for accurate distance.